# Sequence number inside a txt file in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk

I want to generate a unique sequence number for each row in the file in unix. I can not make identity column in database as it has some other sources which also inserts data in it. I tried using NR number in awk but since i have filters in my script it may skip rows in the file so i may not get sequential numbers.
my requirements are - This sequence number needs to be persistent since everday i would receive this file and should start from where i left of. also the number needs to be preceded by "EMP_" for each line in the file.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have tried. You will probably need to parse the last line each time to get the previous ending sequence number and use a counter (`counter++`).

Comment: awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} NR!=1 {print "IMP_"NR,$3, $8, $9 }' filename > newfile notice the NR in print

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain unique id in UNIX you may use file to store and read the value. however this method is so tedious and require mechanism on file IO locking. the easiest way is to use date time to obtain unique id example :

```
#!/bin/sh

uniqueVal = `date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`
```

Comment: example will blow up, given the spaces around the '='. Good luck to all.